# Loads Javascript file but not executing

Tags: javascript, laravel

The code below loads the javascript file as expected but it does not execute the files.

```
    <script src="{{ asset('libs/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('libs/jsvectormap/dist/js/jsvectormap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('libs/jsvectormap/dist/maps/world.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('libs/jsvectormap/dist/maps/world-merc.js') }}"></script>
```

It is placed within the end of body tag, what I'm I missing please? Im working on Laravel 8.

Comment: How can you tell it loads the JS as expected? How can you tell it doesn't execute them? (Since loading and executing are, in this context, the same thing, it seems that both statements can't be true).

Comment: I inspected it and saw the source from the browser which indicates that the js file has been loaded to the browser, however it is not performing it functions.

Comment: "I inspected it and saw the source from the browser which indicates that the js file has been loaded to the browser" — I don't understand what that means. (I can think of at least three different interpretations of that, so please don't assume that it is obvious and I'm being dim).

Comment: "however it is not performing it functions" — What functions? How does the behaviour you get differ from the behaviour you expect?

Comment: Does the console report any errors? If you add logging statements to the scripts, do the log entries appear?

Comment: Looking at the script they are js charts and map from https://github.com/tabler/tabler, i have written the pure html and imported it css in laravel 8. I'm only having problem to make the js files works according to the demo. 

The code i posted was how i imported the js file in laravel which shows on my browser source by inspection but the js files are not working.

Comment: Solved it. It was because I didn't initialize the scripts, that was why it was loading and not executing the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It was because I didn't initialize the scripts, that was why it was loading to browser and not executing.